# Bokeh - draw top and right axes

Tags: python, bokeh

I think this is **very** straightforward, but I cannot find an answer to it. I am trying to have a bokeh scatter plot with both the top and right axis drawn. I would like to have something like this (generated using `gnuplot`):

[image: gnuplot]

Here is my simple `bokeh` code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("test.html")
p = figure()

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_in = 10
p.axis.major_tick_out = 0
p.axis.minor_tick_in = 5
p.axis.minor_tick_out = 0

p.line([-10,10], [-10,10])
show(p)
```

Resulting in:

[image: bokeh]

So I want to be able to mirror the left/right and top/bottom axes. I've tried using `LinearAxis()` in `bokeh` without success. By adding the following lines:

```
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(), 'right')
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(), 'above')
```

I got close, but not quite there yet:

[image: bokeh2]

I did not find a way to remove the numbers on top/right and also have the tic marks inside. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the desired layout based on the accepted answer:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("test.html")
p = figure()

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_in = 10
p.axis.major_tick_out = 0
p.axis.minor_tick_in = 5
p.axis.minor_tick_out = 0

p.add_layout(LinearAxis(major_label_text_alpha=0,
                        minor_tick_in=5,minor_tick_out=0,
                        major_tick_in=10,major_tick_out=0),'right')
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(major_label_text_alpha=0,
                        minor_tick_in=5,minor_tick_out=0,
                        major_tick_in=10,major_tick_out=0),'above')

p.line([-10,10], [-10,10])
show(p)
```

[image: bokeh3]

Comment: Please edit your post to include the actual code that you tried, and also to describe exactly how it did not succeed (no output? wrong output? error message? If so what message?)

Comment: ok, added the `LinearAxis` attempt. thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify text attributes of the tick marks when creating the Axis object:

```
p.add_layout(
    LinearAxis(
       major_label_text_alpha=0
    ),
    'right'
)
```

Here are the relevant docs:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/axes.html

Comment: Thank you! According to the docs, there is no `minor_label_text_alpha`, but other than that it worked after some other tweaking. I'll update the questions with this and accept your answer. Can you edit your answer and remove the `minor_label_text_alpha`?